# Is it possible to use jQuery with Lit-element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, treetable, lit-element

I want to build a custom tree table with Lit element and I was just wondering if I could somehow implement it with the jQuery tree grid plugin.

This is the best what I have now(this solution is not tested with Lit element):

Code:

```js
var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
var i;
var padding = 0;
console.log(this);
console.log(this.parentElement);
for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
  console.log(toggler[i]);

  toggler[i].style.paddingLeft = (padding * 10) + "%";
  var list = toggler[i].parentElement.getElementsByClassName("name");
  var j;
  for (j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
    list[j].style.paddingLeft = (padding * 15) + "%";
  }
  padding++;
  toggler[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.parentElement.querySelector(".nested").classList.toggle("active");
    this.classList.toggle("caret-down");
  });
}
```

```css
ul,
#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#myUL {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.caret {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
}

.caret::before {
  content: "\25B6";
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}

.caret-down::before {
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Safari */
  '
 transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.nested {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  width: 800px;
  /* change it to whatever you like */
  position: relative;
  /* these should be probably already set up by reset.css */
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul:before,
ul:after {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
  width: 48%;
}

li {
  text-align: left;
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

li:nth-child(even) {
  margin-left: -1px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 64px !important;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><span class="caret"><span>Coffee</span></span>
    <ul class="nested">
      <li><span class="name">Coffee</span></li>
      <li><span>Timeline</span></li>
      <li><span class="name">Coffee</span></li>
      <li><span>Timeline</span></li>
      <li><span class="caret"><span>Coffee</span></span>
        <ul class="nested">
          <li><span class="name">Coffee</span></li>
          <li><span>Timeline</span></li>
          <li><span class="caret"><span>Coffee</span></span>
            <ul class="nested">
              <li><span class="name">Coffee</span></li>
              <li><span>Timeline</span></li>
              <li><span class="name">Coffee</span></li>
              <li><span>Timeline</span></li>
              <li><span class="name">Coffee</span></li>
              <li><span>Timeline</span></li>
              <li><span class="name">Coffee</span></li>
              <li><span>Timeline</span></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><span>Timeline</span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span>Timeline</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>Timeline</span></li>
</ul>
```

I don't know what is the general or best solution for this kind of tree table and this was my best guess where should I start without jQuery. Is there a better way of creating this kind of component?

I want to create something like this https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/components/components-treetable.html

I am just curious how tree tables usually implemented on the web.

Comment: My opinion: If that is possible and you do that you will hate yourself for the decision later.

Comment: Do you know how should I solve this problem I could not really find nice solutions for that.
I will update the post with the best thing what I have but I only tested it without Lit-Element

Comment: @TiborFekete You can use `lit-html` with jquery instead `lit-element`... here an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/litelement-how-to-implement-select2-in-litelement

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but there are some really fundamental issues - jQuery makes some base assumptions that were really useful in 2008 but are broken with an asynchronous library like Lit (in particular about when the DOM is ready to manipulate).

You've shared a Vaadin example, but their components all use Lit anyway. I'd recommend using theirs instead of reinventing it.

However, the Lit approach is different from the jQuery. With jQuery you build HTML and then use `$` to traverse the DOM, find elements and hook up events. With Lit you build the HTML from templates and set the events *as* you add it to the DOM (though you might fall back something more similar to jQuery when rehydrating SSR).

To make jQuery work you need to:

- Ensure jQuery has loaded before the component does
- Use `firstUpdated` to ensure that the template has rendered before running jQuery over it
- Ensure that you *don't* replace the DOM with any subsequent Lit change (for instance by using `repeat` rather than `map`)
- If you do add elements you'll need jQuery to find and set them up again.

It would be *considerably* easier to port this code to Lit than to make jQuery work.

Instead of:

```html
<span class="caret"><span>Coffee</span></span>
<ul class="nested">...
```

And

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("caret");
...
... .addEventListener("click" ...
```

You have:

```
html`
<span class="caret" @click=${this.toggleNode}>Coffee</span>
<ul class=${classMap({active: this.expanded, nested: true})}>...`;
```